# PHP Ajax onclick with input parameter

Tags: php, ajax

How do I pass the php ID parameter onclick of a li element......to do a php function with that ID using Ajax, resulting in displaying details for specific id?

```
<li href="" onclick="fetchDetails(<?php echo $singleEmail['email_id']; ?>)" class="emailDetails">Delete</li>
```

Judging by the things I saw online so far, I assume this is not even possible, so I'm probably looking for a workaround or something since I hardly doubt this will work like this.

Also I'm new to Ajax and php as well don't go to hard on me please.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do it, store the PHP ID in a hidden input before li tag and get the PHP value of a hidden field using Javascript on click and than in your JS function of onClick event you can fetch that value from hidden input.

```
<input type="hidden" id="email_id" value="<?php echo $singleEmail['email_id']; ?>" />
<li href="" onclick="fetchDetails()" class="emailDetails">Delete</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function fetchDetails($this){
  //Clicked Element
  console.log($this);
  //Get data by `id` using `.data()`
  console.log(jQuery($this).data('id'));
  //Get data with help of `attr()`
  console.log(jQuery($this).attr('data-email'));
}
```

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li.btn {
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #87CEFA;
  border: 1px solid #00BFFF;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li onclick="fetchDetails(this)" class="btn emailDetails" data-id="100" data-email="xyz@mail.com">Delete</li>
```

You can do it like this.